# Mongoose - Model.updateOne isn't working for me when adding an embeded document to an existing document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I run this code in node.js my embedded document id doesn't match with the related id in the other collection.

```
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
    },
    review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const watermelon = new Fruit({
    name: "Watermelon",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Meh."
});

// watermelon.save();

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number,
    favouriteFruit: fruitSchema
});

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

const person = new Person({
    name: "John",
    age: 37,
    favouriteFruit: watermelon
});

person.save();
```

As a result, in MongoDB I get, From

```
 db.fruits.find()
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5e7444c37ce78dd238d0f994"), 
  "name" : "Watermelon", 
  "rating" : 7,
  "review" : "Meh.", 
  "__v" : 0 
  }
```

From

```
 db.people.find()
   { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7451d971df90096974be01"), 
    "name" : "John",
    "age" : 37, 
    "favouriteFruit" :
    { 
      "_id" : ObjectId("5e7451d971df90096974be00"), 
      "name" :"Watermelon",
      "rating" : 7,
      "review" : "Meh."
    },
        "__v" : 0
    }
```

I think I'm missing something with the Model.updateOne method.
I'm just trying to add an embedded document into another document.
I'm just a beginner, so any links or help would be amazing!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Why such behavior?**
The reason you are having different `_id`s in the two fruits object that are supposed to be the same is that you did not add the `_id` property to the fruit schema and because `_id` is a required property of all MongoDB document, mongoose would help you auto-generate a new `_id` when it creates the query to send to the database. The `_id` it generates when you run `watermelon.save()` is different from the `_id` it generates when you run `person.save()`, this is why you are seeing the two different `_id`s.

**The fix:**
What you need to do is add the `_id` property to the fruit schema(and maybe the person schema to avoid further surprises) and then explicitly generate an `_id` your self before saving the document into the database. 
The fruit schema should be like this after adding the `_id` property:

```
const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 1,
        max: 10,
    },
    review: String
});
```

And when instantiating the fruit model, add the `_id` value yourself:

```
const watermelon = new Fruit({
    _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), // this helps generate a unique objectId
    name: "Watermelon",
    rating: 7,
    review: "Meh."
});
```